# Color Mapping using LUT for BlackAndWhite pic, how to map the mono(maybe luminace) to mono or color value?

Tags: shader, colormap, lookup-tables, color-space, color-mapping

the input param for LUT should be the luminance?
if so, for colorPic: luminance = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b, right?
but for monoPic(blackAndWhite): should it be luminance = r/g/b?(as r==g==b in blackAndWhite pic)

then use the luminance as input of 1D LUT to map it to a custom mono/color value?

is this process right?
thanks!

Comment: Maybe. The topic is complex, and you have a lot of decisions to take. (as you see, if you sum the constants of L, you get 1, so if you do for your B&W, you get that L = r (or g, or b). But you can use your L formula only if you do not need to use 1D LUT (by having 1 LUT you say it is not linear the response. And you should still do with 3D or you will get casts. but it depends on what you are doing. (and usually B&W is calculated with other methods, see the high number you get in photoshop, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A 1D LUT as used in digital content creation (DCC) applications is most typically applied per-image channel. Put another way, irrespective of whether the image is chromatic or achromatic, the discretised function will process each channel the same way. Note that an achromatic image can have either one channel or 3 equal channels.

3x1D LUTs also exist, those typically have a different discretised function for each of the individual R, G and B channels.